# Is it safe to run Ubuntu Live CD on Windows 7 with Bitlocker encryption enabled?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, encryption, bitlocker

I have (working) notebook with Windows 7 and Bitlocker encryption enabled. Is it possible to run (only run, not install) a Live CD (for example Ubuntu Live CD) without affecting or damaging Windows 7? If from Live CD some programs write something to disk, where the data will be written? I don't want to damage in any way Windows installation

Thanks

Comment: An Ubuntu Live CD will not write anything to your hard disc unless you make it do so, eg by mounting it or writing to its device path. A RAM disc is created during boot-up and this is where all work files are written.

Comment: Yes;  It is safe.  Ubuntu will be unable to read a Bitlocker encrypted volume though

Comment: @AFH Actually I've seen an existing swap partition on a hard drive get automatically used by a live ISO, I'm pretty sure it was Ubuntu or Mint (Ubuntu-based). But that's the only time, otherwise other drives are untouched. Would be good to know if there's a boot or kernel code to never use any swap partitions actually

Comment: @Xen2050 - I've never noticed this, but thanks for pointing it out. I'll check the next time I boot a Live CD. It doesn't seem a good idea: the installed system may be hibernated there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A live cd only runs in your systems memory as a ramdisk. As long as you don't install or try to access the encrypted windows disks it shouldn't modify them in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe presuming you are not mounting your encrypted disk partitions with write permissions. Data for programs running on livecd will be written to ramdisk.